# AAC with PhoneGap on Android

Tags: android, cordova, audio-streaming, phonegap-plugins, aac

Is there any existing plugin to play AAC on Android with PhoneGap ? The code should remain the same as it is the primary goal of PhoneGap. But for now, I learned that there doesn't seem to be a native way to play this AAC feed.

I found something with a few Google search, but it turned out to be not what I wanted.